# What is the difference between confidentialPort and securePort for Jetty

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, apache-karaf

I am trying to enable Jetty's https port. Jetty is running inside a a Karaf server.

There are different suggested configs found online though:

- A version from https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/

  ```
    <!-- Use this connector for many frequently idle connections and for
       threadless continuations. -->
   <Call name="addConnector">
       <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
               <Set name="host">
                   <Property name="jetty.host" />
               </Set>
               <Set name="port">
                   <Property name="jetty.port" default="8181" />
               </Set>
               <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
               <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
               <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
               <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
               <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
               <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
           </New>
       </Arg>
   </Call>
  ```
- Another version from https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.5.v20140505/configuring-connectors.html

  ```
   <New id="tlsHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
       <Arg>
           <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
               <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
               <Set name="securePort">
                   <Property name="jetty.tls.port" default="8443"/>
               </Set>
               <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
               <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
               <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>

               <!-- Uncomment to enable handling of X-Forwarded- style headers
               <Call name="addCustomizer">
                   <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
               </Call>
               -->
           </New>
       </Arg>
       <Call name="addCustomizer">
           <Arg>
               <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/>
           </Arg>
       </Call>
  ```

I am not getting any of the two approaches to work. Do you have any hints on how to debug this issue and which aproach is actually correct?

Comment: That Karaf example is using Jetty 7 or Jetty 8, and the Jetty 9.1 example are all EOL (End of Life), don't use those old versions of Jetty. - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thanks, I will switch to a more recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stable (not-EOL) versions of Jetty, such as Jetty 9.4.x ...

The `HttpConfiguration.securePort` (a configuration present on a `ServerConnector`) is the logical port that identifies the secure port seen publicly to your clients.

Take this use case.

1. Browser on Public Internet, requests `https://acme.com/foo`
2. Browser looks up DNS for `acme.com` and gets `210.1.1.1`
3. Browser connects to `210.1.1.1` on port `443`
4. Load Balancer / Proxy is listening on `210.1.1.1:443` and accepts the request.
5. Load Balancer adds `Forwarding` header and connects to internal IP `10.2.2.2:8443`
6. Jetty server listening on `10.2.2.2:8443` accepts the connect and processes the request.

At this point, the configuration on the Jetty server has a `ServerConnector` on port `8443`, which has a `HttpConfiguration.securePort` which is value `443`, as that's the public port that the browser sees.